# Distinct quickfix buffers for vimgrep and make

Tags: vim, makefile, grep

When `make`-ing under Vim, there is often a need to `vimgrep` the files. In such cases, `vimgrep` takes over the quickfix buffer, so one needs to re-make in order to browse remaining compiler errors.

Is there a way to avoid this mess?

Comment: I've experienced it the opposite way---while `vimgrep`-ing through a set of files in my project, I fix as I go and try to `make` sure that everything is good, but that resets the quickfix list. +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have a look at `:cold[er]` (go to older error list) and `:cnew[er]` (go to newer error list); see [`:h quickfix-error-lists`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/help?tag=quickfix-error-lists).

Here is an idea how to integrate it:

```
nnoremap <expr> <F11> (&ft=='qf' ? ":colder" : ":bprev")."\<cr>" 
nnoremap <expr> <F12> (&ft=='qf' ? ":cnewer" : ":bnext")."\<cr>"
```

`F11` (/`F12`) will go to the previous (/next) buffer for most buffers, or to the older (/newer) error list within the quickfix buffer.